# Discrepency between `iw reg get` and the Wi-Fi chip No-IR frequencies

Tags: wifi, intel, iwlwifi, wifi-hotspot, hostapd

I have a Intel AX200 Wi-Fi chip that I would like to use to host an 5Ghz Wi-Fi AP in France.

When I run `iw reg get`, I have this:

```
global
country FR: DFS-ETSI
        (2400 - 2483 @ 40), (N/A, 20), (N/A)
        (5150 - 5250 @ 80), (N/A, 23), (N/A), NO-OUTDOOR, AUTO-BW
        (5250 - 5350 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (0 ms), NO-OUTDOOR, DFS, AUTO-BW
        (5470 - 5725 @ 160), (N/A, 26), (0 ms), DFS
        (5725 - 5875 @ 80), (N/A, 13), (N/A)
        (5945 - 6425 @ 160), (N/A, 23), (N/A), NO-OUTDOOR
        (57000 - 71000 @ 2160), (N/A, 40), (N/A)

phy#0 (self-managed)
country FR: DFS-UNSET
        (2402 - 2437 @ 40), (6, 22), (N/A), AUTO-BW, NO-HT40MINUS, NO-80MHZ, NO-160MHZ
        (2422 - 2462 @ 40), (6, 22), (N/A), AUTO-BW, NO-80MHZ, NO-160MHZ
        (2447 - 2482 @ 40), (6, 22), (N/A), AUTO-BW, NO-HT40PLUS, NO-80MHZ, NO-160MHZ
        (5170 - 5190 @ 160), (6, 22), (N/A), NO-OUTDOOR, AUTO-BW, IR-CONCURRENT, NO-HT40MINUS, PASSIVE-SCAN
        (5190 - 5210 @ 160), (6, 22), (N/A), NO-OUTDOOR, AUTO-BW, IR-CONCURRENT, NO-HT40PLUS, PASSIVE-SCAN
        (5210 - 5230 @ 160), (6, 22), (N/A), NO-OUTDOOR, AUTO-BW, IR-CONCURRENT, NO-HT40MINUS, PASSIVE-SCAN
        (5230 - 5250 @ 160), (6, 22), (N/A), NO-OUTDOOR, AUTO-BW, IR-CONCURRENT, NO-HT40PLUS, PASSIVE-SCAN
        (5250 - 5270 @ 160), (6, 22), (0 ms), DFS, AUTO-BW, NO-HT40MINUS, PASSIVE-SCAN
        (5270 - 5290 @ 160), (6, 22), (0 ms), DFS, AUTO-BW, NO-HT40PLUS, PASSIVE-SCAN
        (5290 - 5310 @ 160), (6, 22), (0 ms), DFS, AUTO-BW, NO-HT40MINUS, PASSIVE-SCAN
        (5310 - 5330 @ 160), (6, 22), (0 ms), DFS, AUTO-BW, NO-HT40PLUS, PASSIVE-SCAN
        (5490 - 5510 @ 240), (6, 22), (0 ms), DFS, AUTO-BW, NO-HT40MINUS, PASSIVE-SCAN
        (5510 - 5530 @ 240), (6, 22), (0 ms), DFS, AUTO-BW, NO-HT40PLUS, PASSIVE-SCAN
        (5530 - 5550 @ 240), (6, 22), (0 ms), DFS, AUTO-BW, NO-HT40MINUS, PASSIVE-SCAN
        (5550 - 5570 @ 240), (6, 22), (0 ms), DFS, AUTO-BW, NO-HT40PLUS, PASSIVE-SCAN
        (5570 - 5590 @ 240), (6, 22), (0 ms), DFS, AUTO-BW, NO-HT40MINUS, PASSIVE-SCAN
        (5590 - 5610 @ 240), (6, 22), (0 ms), DFS, AUTO-BW, NO-HT40PLUS, PASSIVE-SCAN
        (5610 - 5630 @ 240), (6, 22), (0 ms), DFS, AUTO-BW, NO-HT40MINUS, PASSIVE-SCAN
        (5630 - 5650 @ 240), (6, 22), (0 ms), DFS, AUTO-BW, NO-HT40PLUS, PASSIVE-SCAN
        (5650 - 5670 @ 80), (6, 22), (0 ms), DFS, AUTO-BW, NO-HT40MINUS, NO-160MHZ, PASSIVE-SCAN
        (5670 - 5690 @ 80), (6, 22), (0 ms), DFS, AUTO-BW, NO-HT40PLUS, NO-160MHZ, PASSIVE-SCAN
        (5690 - 5710 @ 80), (6, 22), (0 ms), DFS, AUTO-BW, NO-HT40MINUS, NO-160MHZ, PASSIVE-SCAN
        (5710 - 5730 @ 80), (6, 22), (0 ms), DFS, AUTO-BW, NO-HT40PLUS, NO-160MHZ, PASSIVE-SCAN
        (5735 - 5755 @ 80), (6, 22), (N/A), AUTO-BW, NO-HT40MINUS, NO-160MHZ
        (5755 - 5775 @ 80), (6, 22), (N/A), AUTO-BW, NO-HT40PLUS, NO-160MHZ
        (5775 - 5795 @ 80), (6, 22), (N/A), AUTO-BW, NO-HT40MINUS, NO-160MHZ
        (5795 - 5815 @ 80), (6, 22), (N/A), AUTO-BW, NO-HT40PLUS, NO-160MHZ
        (5815 - 5835 @ 20), (6, 22), (N/A), AUTO-BW, NO-HT40MINUS, NO-HT40PLUS, NO-80MHZ, NO-160MHZ
```

If I understand correctly, I cannot change the country of my Wi-Fi board with `iw reg set`, however, although the DFS is unset, the country is correct and if I read this correctly, the 5GHz frequencies are enabled and not "No-IR".

However, running `iw phy0 info` shows me this:

```
                Frequencies:
                        * 5180 MHz [36] (22.0 dBm) (no IR)
                        * 5200 MHz [40] (22.0 dBm) (no IR)
                        * 5220 MHz [44] (22.0 dBm) (no IR)
                        * 5240 MHz [48] (22.0 dBm) (no IR)
                        * 5260 MHz [52] (22.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)
                        * 5280 MHz [56] (22.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)
                        * 5300 MHz [60] (22.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)
                        * 5320 MHz [64] (22.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)
                        * 5340 MHz [68] (disabled)
                        * 5360 MHz [72] (disabled)
                        * 5380 MHz [76] (disabled)
                        * 5400 MHz [80] (disabled)
                        * 5420 MHz [84] (disabled)
                        * 5440 MHz [88] (disabled)
                        * 5460 MHz [92] (disabled)
                        * 5480 MHz [96] (disabled)
                        * 5500 MHz [100] (22.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)
                        * 5520 MHz [104] (22.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)
                        * 5540 MHz [108] (22.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)
                        * 5560 MHz [112] (22.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)
                        * 5580 MHz [116] (22.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)
                        * 5600 MHz [120] (22.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)
                        * 5620 MHz [124] (22.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)
                        * 5640 MHz [128] (22.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)
                        * 5660 MHz [132] (22.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)
                        * 5680 MHz [136] (22.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)
                        * 5700 MHz [140] (22.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)
                        * 5720 MHz [144] (22.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)
                        * 5745 MHz [149] (22.0 dBm)
                        * 5765 MHz [153] (22.0 dBm)
                        * 5785 MHz [157] (22.0 dBm)
                        * 5805 MHz [161] (22.0 dBm)
                        * 5825 MHz [165] (22.0 dBm)
                        * 5845 MHz [169] (disabled)
                        * 5865 MHz [173] (disabled)
                        * 5885 MHz [177] (disabled)
                        * 5905 MHz [181] (disabled)
```

All 5GHz frequencies are either disabled or No IR, except for a few at the end that shouldn't be allowed in Europe. hostapd refuses to run on any 5GHz channel (including the 149 to 165). What is wrong?

- Did I misunderstood the `iw reg get` output?
- Is the `iw reg get` output wrong?

And can I do something about it?

I run Ubuntu 20.04 with Linux 5.4.0-125-generic, and crda 3.18.

Answer (score 0):

I simply seems that the `PASSIVE-SCAN` flags implies `NO-IR`.